# Failed to Install the App, Error : Applicaiton Verification Failed ..in Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm working on apple watch, I've made a sample application & created IPA using distribution certificates. which is working fine in some apple watches and not in some devices.(Note :- both devices OS version is same 8.3 only)

Here is the error message reported on the Apple Watch (given to me by Apple's Review Team): when i install the app

> App Verification Failed

[image]

plz let me know the solution.Thanks for helping...

Comment: Are you sure the iOS version for the Apple Watch is 8.3? I had to change it to 8.2 before submitting my app